# My xubuntu 9.04 laptop won't boot properly

Tags: ubuntu, boot, xubuntu

What steps can I take to determine the cause of the failure?

It's a dual boot system.  I can boot into windows fine.  I can boot Xubuntu using the recovery image though it is very very slow and it gets to the lovely blue landscape login screen.  Enter user name and password and then I get a mouse pointer and a fullscreen light blue background while the hard drive makes lots of noises but nothing ever happens.

Are there any tricks to help me figure out what is going on? Logs I can look at?

Comment: Turned out to be a dying drive and forced fsck interaction.  Live disk boot - copy data - order a new drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output of the *dmesg* command and look at logs in */var/log/*.

If you boot-up is as slow as you describe, errors will most likely show up in the *dmesg* command output. This command shows the kernel output from your current boot.

Comment: It looks like something strange is going on with my linux partition.  There is constant drive noise almost like a clock ticking even while doing nothing.  There are DRDY timeout messages and iostat shows that my CPU is spending 68% of it's time waiting in iowait.
fsck had a few errors but the problem is persisting even though they are now fixed.

Comment: If your HDD has SMART capabilities, follow the instructions here to find out if your drive is inching towards failure: http://superuser.com/questions/23112/intermittent-hdd-problems/23122#23122 . If I were in your position, I'd be backing up my data about now. There seem to be others with similar problems on the Ubuntu forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=937872

Comment: And then it just went away.  I have no clue why.  Odd.

Comment: smartmontools is reporting some UNC sectors and some googling is showing that the Toshiba drive MK8025GAS has some strange issues that match some errors that show up in the logs: 
[ 45.012000] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x2 frozen
[ 45.012000] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:f0:a4:14/00:00:00:00:00/e7 tag 0 cdb 0x1e data 4096 in
[ 45.012000] res 40/00:03:00:00:20/00:00:00:00:00/b0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Not sure where to go from here.